# Удалить все элементы внутри кавычек

Tags: sql-server

Есть текстовое поле, включающее в себя HTML-теги, наподобие:

`<p style="margin-top: 0px;" dir="lt"> ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ  <div id="mail-app-auto">  <p dir="lt">-- Отправлено из Mail.ru для Android </BODY></HTML>`

Нужно вытащить отсюда только текст, удалив при этом все теги. Не совсем понятно, как сделать это именно в MS SQL, при отсутствии REGEXP

Comment: 1) делать на бэке 2) написать скалярную функцию, которая будет искать знаки <> и выдирать значения 3) написать прям экстеншен для сервера со соей юзер-функцией

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует *токенизацию* через XML и XQuery.

Промежуточный XML будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<root>
  <r />
  <r>~p style="margin-top: 0px;" dir="lt"</r>
  <r> ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ </r>
  <r>~div id="mail-app-auto"</r>
  <r>  </r>
  <r>~p dir="lt"</r>
  <r>-- Отправлено из Mail.ru для Android </r>
  <r>~/BODY</r>
  <r />
  <r>~/HTML</r>
  <r />
</root>
```

Итак, нам нужно отфильтровать пустые теги `<r />`, а также теги, имеющие первое значение как намеренно вставленный символ тильды. Это делается с помощью выражения XQuery FLWOR с использованием метода `.query()`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
(N'<p style="margin-top: 0px;" dir="lt"> ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ <div id="mail-app-auto">  <p dir="lt">-- Отправлено из Mail.ru для Android </BODY></HTML>');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

DECLARE @bogus CHAR(1) = '~';

SELECT t.* --,c
    , result = c.query('
        for $x in /root/r[text()]
            [not(substring(text()[1],1,1)=sql:variable("@bogus"))]
            /text()
        return $x
    ').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(tokens, '<', '>' + @bogus)) AS t1(s)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(s, '>', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t2(c)
```

**Результат**

| ID | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ -- Отправлено из Mail.ru для Android |